# How to install google cloud sdk on python 3.5.2

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am following the guide to install google cloud sdk. But when I use the statement

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

I get an error no module named google.apengine.ext. I think it is due to my google cloud sdk not being installed in Python 3.5. So my question is that how to install that package in Python 3.5. Is there a possibility to install it in virtual env?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ndb` client library is only supported in the standard environment for Python 2.7 applications. From  [Using the ndb client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-datastore#using_the_ndb_client_library):

> The ndb client library is not compatible with the Python 3.7 runtime.
>   For more information, see [differences between the Python 2.7 and
>   Python 3.7 runtimes on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences).